# c# TcpListener WebServer cannot send a jpg

Tags: c#, webserver, jpeg

I am trying to send a jpg to a browser.

The problem is with `SendPic(writer, page);`.

I have tried `FileStream` in a couple of ways, the page displays in the browser OK, but no jpg. How can I do this correctly?

```
public void beginserver()
{
    TcpClient newclient = new TcpClient();
    myListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8080);
    myListener.Start();
    isServerRunning = true;
    while (isServerRunning)
    {
        newclient = myListener.AcceptTcpClient();
        HandleClient(newclient);
    }
    myListener.Stop();
}
private void HandleClient(object newclient)
{
    // retrieve client from parameter 
    client = (TcpClient)newclient;
    reader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
    writer = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
    try 
    { 
        string request = reader.ReadLine(); 
        string[] tokens = request.Split(' ');
        string page = tokens[1];
        if (page == "/" )
        {
            //send index.html
        } 
        else if (page.Contains(".jpg")) 
        {
            //send pic
            SendPic(writer,page);
        }
        else
        {
            //error code
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //error 404
        writer.WriteLine("HTTP/1.1 404 OK\n");
        writer.WriteLine("<h1> Sorry file not found! 
                          ... <h1>");
        writer.Flush();
    }
    client.Close();
}
public void SendHTMLFile(string page)
{
    //code ...
}
public void SendPic(StreamWriter writer, string page)
{
    //Problem    
    byte[] ar;
    using (FileStream fstream = new FileStream(page, 
        FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        ar = new byte[(long)fstream.Length];
        fstream.Read(ar, 0, (int)fstream.Length);
        writer.WriteLine(ar);
        writer.Flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: HTTP uses TCP as the transport layer.  You have a webserver (port 89080) and data has to meet html format which doesn't allow binary data.  So you need to do one of following 1) convert jpg to a base 64 string 2) Put the binary into a MIME attachment to the body of the message.  Mime attachments can be binary.

Comment: If you want to create a webserver, use some existing one, do not try to write your own using tcpListner. For example by creating a "ASP.Net Web API" project, and following some example for how to return a file. Tcp is a low level protocol, if you just want to make computers communicate over a network there are much better options: REST, gRPC, Zero MQ, and many others.

Comment: Thanks jdweng

I changed to Sockets, and now it Works ...